# How can I change the font and color of the Navigation Bar back button

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I am trying to change the font and color of the Navigation Bar button.

[image: Screenshot]

Ideally, I'd like to change it to black and use a custom font that I already have set up. Is there any way to modify the existing button?

I tried this in my view's init for the font

```swift
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [.font : UIFont(name: "Georgia-Bold", size: 20)!]
```

But I think this only changes the title of an inline Nav bar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a `UIBarButtonItem` so set this property.

```
init() {
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = .red
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)], for: .normal)
}
```

Or you can use this also,

```
init() {
    let standard = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    
    let button = UIBarButtonItemAppearance(style: .plain)
    button.normal.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
    standard.buttonAppearance = button
}
```

Comment: For second option; The created UINavigationBarAppearance instance must be assigned to the UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance field.

`UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = standard`

Answer (score 1):

You can do the method above or:

Go to your Assets -> Set a colour for Accent, although this will affect other components in your app i.e. DisclosureGroup button etc.